# Stack overflow error in C# - but how to fix it?

Tags: c#, stack-overflow

I've run into a really interesting runtime bug which generates a rogue stack overflow.

I've defined a structure as follows:

```
public enum EnumDataType { Raspberry, Orange, Pear, Apple };

public class DataRequest
{
    public long DataSize 
    { 
        get { return 0; } 
        set { DataSize = value; } 
    }

    public EnumDataType DataType  
    { 
        get { return EnumDataType.Apple; } 
        set { DataType = value; } 
    }
}
```

The following lines work perfectly:

```
DataRequest request = new DataRequest();
request.DataSize = 60;
```

However, when I step over the following line in code, it generates a stack overflow:

```
request.DataType = EnumDataType.Raspberry;
```

Of course, I can fix it by removing the defaults, or using auto get/set, but I need it to be both readable and writable, and return a default - any ideas?

Comment: I would expect invoking *either* of those setters to cause a stack overflow, whatever value you supplied. Perhaps you could offer a short but complete program to demonstrate the first one "[work]ing perfectly" ?

Comment: I think everyone at some point has done this :)

Comment: I've always found Stackoverflow errors to be quite amusing errors when they crop up, since the few times I have seen them they usually involve two or more methods that are beautifully named inverses of each other. Instead of containing any functional code they reference each other, which would be so wonderful if it worked, but nope. The future has yet to come.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As others have said, the stack overflow occurs because your property setter is just calling itself. It may be simpler to understand if you think of it as a method:

```
// This obviously recurses until it blows up
public void SetDataType(long value)
{
    SetDataType(value);
}
```

As I understand it, you're trying to create normal properties but with a default value, right?

In that case, you need backing variables which are set by the setters - and the getters should return those variables, too. It's the *variables* which should get default values:

```
private long dataSize = 0;
public long DataSize {
  get { return dataSize; }
  set { dataSize = value; }
}

private EnumDataType dataType = EnumDataType.Apple;
public EnumDataType DataType { 
  get { return dataType; }
  set { dataType = value; }
}
```

Alternatively, use automatic properties but set the defaults in your constructor:

```
public long DataSize { get; set; }
public EnumDataType DataType { get; set; }

public DataRequest()
{
    DataSize = 0; // Not really required; default anyway
    DataType = EnumDataType.Apple;
}
```

Comment: Thanks - great answer. I understand exactly whats going on now. We're not dealing with properties, we're dealing with methods, as its an object. The reason behind my original question was how to set the defaults that are returned, and your answer covers this. p.s. Enjoyed your talk in London at the start of this year - your presentation was genuinely interesting, and not just because of the sock puppets :)

Answer (score 20):

```
public long DataSize { get { return 0; } set { DataSize = value; } }
```

You are constantly setting the value of `DataSize`.  You need to create a local variable and use that instead. e.g.

```
private long dataSize;

public long DataSize
{
    get { return this.dataSize; }
    set { this.dataSize = value; }
}
```

**EDIT**
I've written `DataSize` but the same applies to `DataType`

Comment: +8 but no explanation of why the stack overflow occurs?

Comment: -1: This will still *always* return 0 instead of just making 0 the *default* value. Admittedly the question isn't clear, but I don't think it's what was meant.

Comment: @John Nicholas: That is because the program is trying to set DataSize with DataSize, that in turn wants to set it's DataSize with DataSize, which will set that one's DataSize with DataSize. And then it will set it's DataSize with DataSize, after that it will set the DataSize with DataSize… Whew, mindblowing; and I'm not even half-way there!

Comment: I know why ;) the origional asker didn't though ;)

Comment: Thanks - great answer. I understand exactly whats going on now. We're not dealing with properties, we're dealing with methods, as its an object.

Comment: you are dealing with properties ... but your properties were self referencing so they called themselves over and over (hence the stack overflow) ... properties are methods in a way (I suppose in msil they are the same) the difference is that because you canassign to them they are easier to use in expressions. They also carry the implication/expectation of not being expensive unlike a method which could use all kinds of resources and take any amount of time to complete.

Answer (score 4):

stack overflow happens because in the setter you are setting the property to a value (Ie you are trying to get something to set itself to something ... which causes an infinite loop) ... which means that it tries to set itself to a value which means its tries to set itself to a value untill boom

your properties will never get the values you are setting because they always return the same value (not the stored value)

```
public enum EnumDataType { Raspberry, Orange, Pear, Apple }; 

public class DataRequest 
{ 
private long _dataSize = 0;
private EnumDataType _dataType = EnumDataType.Apple;

public long DataSize { get { return _dataSize ; } set { _dataSixe= value; } } 
public EnumDataType DataType  { get { return _dataType; } set { _dataType= value; } } 
}
```

is what you really wanted

Answer (score 3):

you have to implemet it with a backing store:

```
private EnumDataType dataType;
public EnumDataType DataType  { get { return EnumDataType.Apple; } set { dataType = value; } }
```

}

You should do so anytime you do some acion in the getter and setters. By the way, why can you even set the variables? you can't read them out, you always get EnumDataType.Apple. If you want a start value, you can do like this:

```
private EnumDataType dataType = EnumDataType.Apple;
public EnumDataType
{
   get
   {
       return dataType;
   }
   set
   {
       dataType = value;
   }
 }
```

Comment: That won't compile - EnumDataType is a non-nullable value type.

Answer (score 2):

I don't understand how the first line:
request.DataSize = 60;

Doesn't cause a stack overflow - my advice would be to use backing properties:

```
public class DataRequest
{
    protected int dataSize = 0;
    protected EnumDataType enumDataType;
    public long DataSize { get { return 0; } set { dataSize = value; } }
    public EnumDataType DataType  { get { return EnumDataType.Apple; } set { enumDataType = value;} 
}
```