# Why does this button object cause a stack overflow?

Tags: c#

```
 void OpenClean( int i, int j) {

        bnt[i, j] = new Button();
        if (!bnt[i,j].Enabled) return;

        bnt[i, j].Enabled = false;
        bnt[i,j].BackColor = Color.Aquamarine;
        bnt[i, j].Text = data[i, j].ToString();
        if (data[i, j] == 0) {

            if (i > 0 && j > 0 && data[i - 1, j - 1] == 0) OpenClean(i - 1, j - 1);
            if (i > 0 && data[i - 1, j] == 0) OpenClean(i - 1, j);
            if (i > 0 && j < 8 && data[i - 1, j + 1] == 0) OpenClean(i - 1, j + 1);
            if (j > 0 && data[i, j - 1] == 0) OpenClean(i, j - 1);
            if (j < 8 && data[i, j + 1] == 0) OpenClean(i, j + 1);
            if (i < 8 && j > 0 && data[i + 1, j - 1] == 0) OpenClean(i + 1, j - 1);
            if (i < 8 && data[i + 1, j] == 0) OpenClean(i + 1, j);
            if (i < 8 && j < 8 && data[i + 1, j + 1] == 0) OpenClean(i + 1, j + 1);
        }
```

It tells me **Process is terminated due to StackOverflowException.**
Because of my limited experience,I didn't find an effective way.
This question has been bothering me for a long time.
Please help or try to give me some ideas how to solve it.

**Thanks in advance!**

Comment: You are calling your `OpenClean` method recusively. I didn't check all your conditions, (and I'm not able to, because I don't know the contents of the `data` array) but probably you have an error in your conditions, so your recursive calling never stops. Which after some time results in a StackOverflow exception

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I prevent and/or handle a StackOverflowException?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/206820/how-do-i-prevent-and-or-handle-a-stackoverflowexception) and [Stack overflow error in C# - but how to fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4033805/stack-overflow-error-in-c-sharp-but-how-to-fix-it)

Comment: This is a good time to learn how to use the debugger. Put a breakpoint on the method. When the program stops, look at the _call stack_ write down what the parameters are. Step, step, step. Keep stepping till you call the method again (you'll then hit your breakpoint again). It should become obvious what's happening

Answer (score 0):

You never set `data[i, j]` to a value other than `0`. Therefore, the recursion never stops. You must set the inspected cells to a different value so that they will not get inspected again and again and again ...

You also create a new button with `bnt[i, j] = new Button();` instead of inspecting the existing button. Therefore you will never see a button with `Enabled == false`, since the [default value for `Enabled` is `true`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.enabled?view=net-5.0#property-value).

It is better to base the logic on the model (i.e. `data[,]`) and to use the UI (the controls) only for display.

```cs
const int Inspected = -1;
```

```cs
void OpenClean( int i, int j) {
    ...
    if (data[i, j] == 0) {
        data[i, j] = Inspected; // <====== This stops the endless recursion!
        if (i > 0 && j > 0 && data[i - 1, j - 1] == 0) OpenClean(i - 1, j - 1);
        ...
    }
}
```

And, btw., you are testing for `0` twice. Before calling `OpenClean` and inside `OpenClean` again. Just do it once.

```cs
void OpenClean( int i, int j) {
    if (data[i, j] == 0) { // This one does the job.
        data[i, j] = Inspected; // <======
        // bnt[i, j] = new Button();  <=== drop this!
        // if (!bnt[i,j].Enabled) return;  <=== drop this! We test data instead.

        bnt[i, j].Enabled = false;
        bnt[i,j].BackColor = Color.Aquamarine;
        bnt[i, j].Text = data[i, j].ToString();

        if (i > 0 && j > 0) OpenClean(i - 1, j - 1);
        if (i > 0         ) OpenClean(i - 1, j);
        if (i > 0 && j < 8) OpenClean(i - 1, j + 1);
        if (         j > 0) OpenClean(i,     j - 1);
        if (         j < 8) OpenClean(i,     j + 1);
        if (i < 8 && j > 0) OpenClean(i + 1, j - 1);
        if (i < 8         ) OpenClean(i + 1, j);
        if (i < 8 && j < 8) OpenClean(i + 1, j + 1);
    }
}
```

If you do the range test at the beginning of `OpenClean`, you can get rid of all the other range tests.

```cs
void OpenClean( int i, int j) {
    if (i > 0 && i < 8 && j > 0 && j < 8 && data[i, j] == 0) { // This one does the job.
        data[i, j] = Inspected; // <======

        bnt[i, j].Enabled = false;
        bnt[i,j].BackColor = Color.Aquamarine;
        bnt[i, j].Text = data[i, j].ToString();

        OpenClean(i - 1, j - 1);
        OpenClean(i - 1, j);
        OpenClean(i - 1, j + 1);
        OpenClean(i,     j - 1);
        OpenClean(i,     j + 1);
        OpenClean(i + 1, j - 1);
        OpenClean(i + 1, j);
        OpenClean(i + 1, j + 1);
    }
}
```

Using the C# 9.0 patterns, you can simplify the condition somewhat

```cs
if (i is > 0 and < 8 && j is > 0 and < 8 && data[i, j] == 0)
```